# Where to put general language adjustment?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, internationalization

Well, the title says it all.

I do the following now in my LanguageFilterAttribute class:

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var request         = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        string currentUrl   = request.RawUrl;
        var urlHelper       = new UrlHelper(request.RequestContext);

        string baseurl                      = urlHelper.Content("~");
        string currentLanguageFromUrl       = currentUrl.Split('/')[1];
        string currentLanguageFromCulture   = CultureHelper.CheckCulture();
        var currentLanguageFromCookie       = request.Cookies["_culture"];

        var possibleCultures                = UnitOfWork.CulturesRepository.GetListOfCultureNames();

        if (possibleCultures.All(culture => currentLanguageFromUrl != culture))
        {
            string cultureName;
            string newUrl;

            if (currentLanguageFromCookie != null)
            {
                cultureName = currentLanguageFromCookie.Value;
                CultureHelper.SetCulture(cultureName);
                newUrl = baseurl + cultureName;
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(newUrl);
                return;
            }

            if (currentLanguageFromCulture != null)
            {
                cultureName = currentLanguageFromCulture;
                CultureHelper.SetCulture(cultureName);
                newUrl = baseurl + cultureName;
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(newUrl);
                return;
            }

            cultureName = possibleCultures[0];
            CultureHelper.SetCulture(cultureName);
            newUrl = baseurl + cultureName;
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(newUrl);
            return;
        }

        CultureHelper.SetCulture(currentLanguageFromUrl);

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    };
```

Which sets the language when you select a new one from the dopdown on the shared Layout page (this works btw, selecting a different language triggers respectively, the above and below class correctly).

```
    public static void SetCulture(string culture)
    {
        var cultureCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["_culture"] ?? new HttpCookie("_culture");
        cultureCookie.Value = culture;
        var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;

        cultureCookie.Domain = request.Url.Host;

        cultureCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
        cultureCookie.Path = "/";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cultureCookie);

        CultureInfo info = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture.ToString());

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = info;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = info;

    }
```

The problem with this is, as you can guess, I will have to apply the [LanguageFilter] attribute on all my controllers.
Isn't there a file where I can place this that will change my language every time I go to another page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx

> When a new application thread is started, its current culture and
>   current UI culture are defined by the current system culture, and not
>   by the current thread culture.

Isn't this your case?

Comment: Yes, I apply that but the problem is that the logic to adjust it, is now located in an actionfilter, this now requires me to always add [LanguageFilter] at the top of every single controller I have before it actually works. Of course, this is not what I want, I want it to work everywhere.